# What is a word that describes someone who hurts people without meaning to?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that describes a person who hurts people without meaning to (as in not intentionally)?

Comment: Do you mean hurting them with words or physically hurting them?

Answer (score 3):

"Reckless", "careless" or "negligent" all mean roughly the same thing:

> "Not giving sufficient attention or thought, especially concerning the avoidance of harm or mistakes." (Wiktionary)

The reckless person might hurt themselves or other people - that's ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

You could you "*clumsy*" for hurting physically, and "*tactless*" for hurting emotionally.

See the following from subscription-only LDOCE:

> **tactless (adj.)**: someone who is tactless says or does things that offend other people or hurt their feelings, without intending to and
>   without realizing that they have done it:
>
> *He made all sorts of tactless remarks about her appearance.*
>
> **-> it's tactless (of somebody) to do something:**
>
> *It was a bit tactless of you to start talking about her ex-boyfriend.*

---

> **clumsy (adj.)**:
>
> 1. **moving or doing things in a careless way, especially so that you drop things, knock into things, etc.**:
>
>    *A clumsy waiter spilled wine all over her new skirt.*
> 2. a clumsy object is not easy to use and is often large and heavy
> 3. **a clumsy action or statement is said or done carelessly or badly, and likely to upset someone**:
>
>    *David made a clumsy attempt to comfort us.*

P.S. "*[**insensitive**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/insensitive)*" is another related word, however it doesn't exactly imply that the person is actually *doing* something hurtful, but just *not noticing* how the others are feeling hurt.

Answer (score 0):

One who unwittingly hurts people while going about their daily business can sometimes be called "train wreck", a "ticking time bomb", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Oblivious, I believe that is the word you might be searching for.

oblivious |əˈblivēəs|
adjective
not aware of or not concerned about what is happening around one: she became absorbed, oblivious to the passage of time | the women were oblivious of his presence.

oblivious
adjective
oblivious to the conversation around the table | utterly and happily oblivious of the effect he was having upon his audience: unaware of, unconscious of, heedless of, unmindful of, insensible of/to, unheeding of, ignorant of, incognizant of, blind to, deaf to, unsuspecting of, unobservant of; insensitive to, unconcerned with, impervious to, unaffected by, indifferent to; informal clueless. ANTONYMS aware, conscious, sensitive.

Comment: Please state and link to the sources of the definitions you quote.

Answer (score -1):

#1) I.D.10.T Problem

#2) Sociamantectomy: Socially inept people who have lost all manners.

#3) Vitamin IQ Deficiency: The lack of Basic Intelligence

#4) Foot in Mouth Disease

#5) Microdeckia: Someone who isn't playing with a full deck

#6) Obnoxious Genitalia: Self Explained

#7) Pheumoencephalopathy: Airhead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).