# The one who Hurts

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word used for the person who Hurts you?

I have seen the answers [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126385/what-is-a-word-that-could-define-someone-who-likes-to-cause-conflict), the question is *someone who hurts knowingly*.   Also [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188028/what-is-a-word-that-describes-hurting-people-without-meaning-to), but someone who hurts unintentionally.

To explain my question, I'm using one quote:

> You see a person's true colors when you are no longer beneficial in their life.

What do we call for such person?

Comment: Perhaps [***sadist***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/169652?redirectedFrom=sadist#eid)

Comment: *torturer* if the hurting is literal.

Comment: *Tormentor*...?

Comment: @WS2 I was searching the meaning of _Tormentor_ but found only Torment=great mental suffering and unhappiness, or great physical pain. So my understanding is, Tormentor is the one who is suffering, I'm in right?

Comment: @KrishnShweta No, a *tormentor* is someone doing the tormenting. The person suffering is *the tormented*.

Comment: @DavidHandelman  Thanks, it is matching to the word which I want.

Comment: @WS2 Oh!! I see. I've learned so many new words from this answers and comments.  **Thanks a lot all**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the word used for the person who Hurts you?
>
> To explain my question, I'm using one quote:
>
> You see a person's true colors when you are no longer beneficial in
>   their life.

It seems to me that such a person is **selfish** or **narcissistic**.

> [**selfish**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/selfish): devoted to or
>   caring only for oneself; concerned primarily with one's own interests,
>   benefits, welfare, etc., regardless of others
>
> [**narcissistic**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/narcissist):
>   refers to someone intensely concerned with only his or her own self or
>   interests and who seems to forget that others exist

When you are "**no longer beneficial in their life**", such a person moves on without a care in the world, because *the only thing that matters to them is them*. What "**Hurts**" is that you care, but they don't.

Being **selfish** or **narcissistic** is not the same as being a *user* or an *exploiter*, each of which implies intentionality. People who are **selfish** or **narcissistic** are so self-absorbed that they use and exploit without even realizing it. It's always all about them. They're not *parasites* either: parasites at least know they're parasites.

If you're seeking a less commonly used word, **narcissistic** fits the bill.

Comment: Thanks Richard Kayseri. I'm looking for the word which is not commonly used. Can you add one more similar word to this which is rarely used ?

Comment: @KrishnShweta You didn't say anything in your question about the word being not commonly used. :-) I'll add another option.

Comment: Yeah, true. I apologize ^.^

Comment: @KrishnShweta No worries. Let me know if you like the new word. It has the same connotations as **selfish**, but is not nearly as commonly used.

Comment: That's really cool. Thanks Richard. I'll look at it's pronunciation :-)

Comment: @KrishnShweta If you're happy, I'm happy. Have a good night. I've enjoyed pondering your question.

Answer (score 0):

"You see a person's true colors when you are no longer beneficial in their life." If such a person no longer valued your friendship or companionship after you stopped becoming "beneficial" or useful to them, they'd be a

> user.

A "user" is someone who uses people for personal gain. Characteristically, a user would no longer associate with someone when they could no longer profit or benefit from the relationship.

Other terms might be:

> parasite

or

> exploiter

Comment: "He is a parasite",  Is it correct?

Comment: @KrishnShweta, yes. Be aware that it's very insulting, which is the point.

Comment: I think no need of bothering about the insult, because the person is using others for his benefits. Thanks John :)

Comment: @KrishnShweta, Exactly!

Comment: A *user* is inherently non-specific, but by default today the unqualified version is generally understood to mean someone who uses software or technical equipment. Not that any of this seems relevant to OP's context, but the context you're talking about would generally be expressed as *He [just] **uses** people [and discards them when they're no longer useful]*.

Comment: John I have used that word for that _parasite man_ . His face was LOL. Thanks a lot :-)